# Select menu not being updated with new information that has been added

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Initially when the page loads, ajax populates a selectmenu.  When I enter new patient information it is added to the database but the patient selectmenu does not get append to/refresh with that new patient being selected.

I was hoping someone could help me with what Im doing wrong.

Ajax call

```
$('#newpatient').click(function() {
    var patientadd = $('#patientaddform').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'patientadd.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: patientadd,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].patient_id + '">' + data[i].patient_firstname + ' ' + data[i].patient_lastname + '</option>';
            }
            $('#patientselect').append(html);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#patientselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    });
});​
```

patientadd.php

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $update_data = array('company_id' = > $_POST['company_id'], 'addpatient_firstname' = > $_POST['addpatient_firstname'], 'addpatient_lastname' = > $_POST['addpatient_lastname'], 'addpatient_dob' = > $_POST['addpatient_dob'], 'patient_added' = > $_POST['patient_added']);


    $required_fields = array('company_id', 'addpatient_firstname', 'addpatient_lastname', 'addpatient_dob', 'patient_added');
    foreach($update_data as $key = > $value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1;
        }
    }
}

if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

    $company_id = $_POST['company_id'];
    $patient_id = $_POST['addpatient_id'];
    $first_name = $_POST['addpatient_firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['addpatient_lastname'];
    $dob = $_POST['addpatient_dob'];
    $updated = $_POST['patient_added'];


    $update = array();
    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

    foreach($update_data as $field = > $data) {
        $update[] = '`'.$field.'` = \''.$data.'\'';
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `lab`.`patients` (`company_id`,  `patient_id`, `patient_firstname`, `patient_lastname`, `patient_dob`, `patient_added`) VALUES ('$company_id', NULL, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$dob', '$updated')");
    $patient_id = mysql_insert_id(); /*echo '<strong>' . $patient_id . ' ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '</strong> has been added!';*/
}

$data = array('patient_id' = > $patient_id, 'patient_firstname' = > $first_name, 'patient_lastname' = > $last_name);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move you code from `complete` to the `success` function.

```
$('#newpatient').click(function() {
    var patientadd = $('#patientaddform').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'patientadd.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: patientadd,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].patient_id + '">' + data[i].patient_firstname + ' ' + data[i].patient_lastname + '</option>';
            }
            $('#patientselect').append(html);
            $('#patientselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            //$('#patientselect').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    });
});​
```

Ajax executes is asynchronous. The `success` method only executes ones the request returns. However, ones `success` is triggered, so is `complete`. This means you end up in a race-condition in which `complete` executes before `success` is finished executing. `Complete` does not wait for `success` to finish. `success` and `complete` pretty much execute simultaneously.

To ensure your refresh call includes the new data execute refresh within the `success` following the `append`.

Comment: @Adam: If you add `console.log(data)` or `console.log(data.length)` as the first line within the success function, do you definitely get the new data included in the returned `data` value?

Comment: I think the json data is coming back with all null values. I apologize, I added the console.log(data), but Im not sure how to check your question.

Comment: @Adam: You see the result of the output of a console.log in the browser debugging tool. In Chrome/IE for example you can press F12 and in FF you can use the FireBug AddOn. The outpur will show you the content of the data object. If you are not getting back the expected data than your issue is within your php code. I don't know how to debug php though. Ones that is fixed you may still need to apply the work-around I posted as `complete` still can execute before `success` is finished, causing the new item not to be displayed.

Comment: @francios I replaced console.log(data) with alert(data) and it returned [object Object]. Does that help with your question?

Comment: @Adam: You can't alert out an object due to it being displayed as [object object]. You have to use your browsers debugging tool, open the console there and watch the results of "console.log(data)". I suppose you could alert out the elements in the result, ie: `alert(data[0])` and check what you get there but to properly debug you need to figure out how to use your browser debugging tools.

Comment: @francios: I was trying to check it using dreamweaver.  I alerted out the html and it is coming back BLANK.  I alerted out the initial selectmenu ajax when the document gets loaded and it came back with all the options, so Im pretty sure the php is passing blank json data.

Comment: @Adam: That's good at least you know now where to look for the issue. As I mentioned above I don't know how to debug your php code. I don't know why your sql call is not retuning the data.

Comment: @francios I think I need to make another mysql query to retrieve the last input into the database on the php page and pass that encoded.

Comment: @Adam: Did you manage to your SQL sorted out? did you have to move the refresh call into the `success` method?

Comment: @francios No I havent gotten it to work.  I keep getting a NULL return.  Im working on it now, I'll definitely let you know.